# Slow loading webpage CKeditor not authorized one css file

Tags: asp-classic, ckeditor

Slowdown issue is only in Internet Explorer (10).

IE loading time: 30 sec. Firefox and Chrome: 5 sec. Profiler shows that problem file is CKeditor library with on file: contents.css. Please see images: IE:

[image]

(after fully loaded page= 30 sec can user work)

And Firefox:

[image]

(after 5 sec user can work with webpage)

My ASP webpages are in LAN in IIS on Winserver. I am using Win7. CKeditor is latest stable version from [developers](http://ckeditor.com/download).

EDIT:
After solving error 401 issue, there is log of loading files in IE:
[image: After solving error 401 issue]
Still about 30 seconds loading...

Comment: What DocType you using have you tried others?

Comment: I tried all these doctype declarations: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: Try to open `content.css?t=E6FD` resource directly from IE, and post here detailed error message. If error details is not showing change IIS settings.

Comment: Weird permissions issue on that one resource, have you tried reapplying permissions to `content.css` on the server?

Comment: @Lankymart yes, I tried compare permission on file with another file. It is same permissions.  

@VMV contets.css is accessible also with `contents.css?t=E6FD`. As You can see from first of my picture- there are 2 IIS errors: 304 and 401. 304 cannot switch to detailed error, because IIS said, that only error between 400-999 I can manage. 401 detailed error has no output and `c:\intepub\custerr` has no usefull error log files. Some more advices please?

Comment: Make sure css is listed as static content.  It looks like the css files are being requested many times because IIS sees them as dymamic content, and perhaps is pushing wrong headers.  Also make sure you dont have any weird rewrite rules such as / after css which could cause a ton of redirects.   Look over the headers for one of the requests (on ie) and let us know what you see there.  (response headers)

Comment: css file is not included in my webpage. My webpage include only js file, see [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation). So, If I will be change css linking, I will be fixing developers bug. Rewrite rules I post there later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Status code 401 is a permissions error. Specifically status code 401 is "unauthorized". This means you are passing either "Basic" or "Windows" authentication and your user doesn't have rights. You'd be getting this error because you've either misconfigured IIS or as mentioned, whatever user you're logged in as doesn't have NTFS permissions to access this file.

You can drill all the way down to the file in question by opening IIS, drilling down to the folder that contains this file, right clicking the folder and choosing "Switch to Content View":

[image]

Then clicking the file and choosing "Switch to Features View":

[image]

Then, when in the features view opening the "Authentication" feature:

[image]

Comment: excelent post! I can see that this adivce solve my problem with #401 returned status code. But not with slow loading page. So, there is another question: is anyway, how to tell IE, that it can use webpage and continue gathering rest parts of webpage on background? Just like Firefox- it can use my webpage after 5 sec...

Comment: Can you post another log with the 401's taken care of? It's hard to say exactly what's going on without seeing the code.

Comment: You have right, I added new screenshot to the my top post. Thx.

Comment: Unfortunately I think there is not enough information here to solve your problem if this did not fix it. I think the CSS may be loaded dynamically and you will need to review the JavaScript or ASP code that is doing this to see why it's happening.

Comment: Unfortunately the code of webpage has more than 5000 lines of codes. Any idea what search specifically?

Comment: I would search the JS for "css" and start commenting out sections until I figured out what part of the code was rendering this. Then I'd try to figure out what that section of code was doing.